# show gateway IP address when performing ifconfig command

Tags: linux, ip

Currently, when using the `ifconfig` command, the following IP addresses are shown:
own IP, broadcast and mask.

Is there a way to show the related gateway IP address as well (on the same screen with all the others, not by using 'route' command)?

Comment: The addresses shows are parameters of the IP configuration of the interface. The gateway is a system routing parameter, not an interface parameter. It wouldn't make sense to show it in the interface configuration.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can with the `ip` command, and given that `ifconfig` is in the process of being deprecated by most distributions it's now the preferred tool.  An example:

```
$ ip route show
212.13.197.0/28 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 212.13.197.13
default via 212.13.197.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: also we can use `ip r` which shows the same.

Comment: So the gateway is '212.13.197.1' in this example?

Comment: `route -n` is so much cleaner of an output..

Comment: @Mayhem - Too bad "route -n" doesn't work for mac. Now "route -n get default" does work for showing the gateway on mac, but the one you suggested works on linux and not mac.

Comment: @SenorContento good thing the question was about linux and not a mac.

Comment: **For scripting:** `ip route show | sed 's/\(\S\+\s\+\)\?default via \(\S\+\).*/\2/p; d'`

Comment: "route -n get default", see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782658/how-to-get-default-gateway-in-mac-osx

Answer (score 17):

Run:

```
$ route
```

The output is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 8):

No, there isn't. According to the man page you can't modify the output of ifconfig (except showing disabled interfaces, too).